# phpmyadmin query export issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running a sql query against a MySQL database using phpmyadmin.   The query is fine; the results show in the results pane.   However when I attempt to export it to a CSV file, it (apparently randomly) picks a table in the query and exports that rather than the query results on the screen.   I know very little about phpmyadmin but this seems odd.    Any advice very much appreciated.

Comment: Uhm... probably not the issue, but just in case: are you hitting the `export` button on the bottom of the query result page?

Comment: Yes I am!   However, I as said above, it doesn't actually export the results of the rather complex query, just what appears to be a random table ...